# How to shorten timestamps on heroku logs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

**Note:** This only happens in apps that I have more than one "process". In this case, I'm using `Resque` so I got one to read the queue, and one to run the jobs on the queue.

This is just an example of the logs I have when I run `heroku logs`. Does anyone know why the time stamps get repeated twice? Is there a disable option? I looked at the Heroku docs and didn't see any. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging

```
  2016-09-21T05:12:34.858759+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-09-21T05:12:34.858696 #3]  INFO -- : [ee72ed1c-fd13-466b-a463-351584a99ad7] Completed
    500 Internal Server Error in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
    2016-09-21T05:12:34.860088+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-09-21T05:12:34.860032 #3] FATAL -- : [ee72ed1c-fd13-466b-a463-351584a99ad7]
    2016-09-21T05:12:34.854247+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2016-09-21T05:12:34.854153 #3]  INFO -- : [ee72ed1c-fd13-466b-a463-351584a99ad7] Started POST "/request_jobs" for 72.89.67.94 at 2016-09-21 05:12:34 +0000
    2016-09-21T05:12:34.860164+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-09-21T05:12:34.860113 #3] FATAL -- : [ee72ed1c-fd13-466b-a463-351584a99ad7] Redis::CannotConnectError (Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)):
    2016-09-21T05:12:34.860223+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-09-21T05:12:34.860183 #3] FATAL -- : [ee72ed1c-fd13-466b-a463-351584a99ad7]
    2016-09-21T05:12:34.860300+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2016-09-21T05:12:34.860239 #3] FATAL -- : [ee72ed1c-fd13-466b-a463-351584a99ad7] app/controllers/hunter_controller.rb:9:in `request_jobs'
```

Answer (score 2):

I asked a similar question and got a great answer that worked for me:

`heroku logs | cut -d "]" -f4`

It seems to go to 4 spaces in front of the last closing square bracket and cut away everything before it.

Hope it helps you too!